# Force a file to be closed

Tags: c#

I am reading, then writing to a text file. I do this in multiple parts of my program. After I'm done writing, I always close it (I use streamreader/writer). There is usually about 3 seconds between the close and the next time it's opened.

However, the second time I need to write to the same file, I always get an access denied error because another process is using it. At no point is any other process ever using it, and restarting my program lets me read from it.

This is the open/write/close code:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileLocation.Text);
file.WriteLine(account);
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming there is no multi-threading then the issue is with proper disposal.  The correct way to dispose of a stream or in general types that implement `IDisposable` is to wrap them in a using statement.  The using statement ensures proper disposal and uses a finally block to ensure that the stream is closed even in exceptional circumstances.

```
using(var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileLocation.Text))
{
  //do work...
  file.WriteLine(account);
}//when file goes out of scope it will close
```

Do this for all your streams.

Answer (score 2):

use `using` statement or `try{ }finally{ file.Close(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure an exception isn't being thrown, preventing close from being called? Either way this is better code:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileLocation.Text))
{
    file.WriteLine(account);
}
```